# RestSharp Deserialize List<object> returns Could not cast or convert from System.String to

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, deserialization, restsharp

I know that there are many topics about this, hover, I can't find a solution or figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Scenario:

```
There are 2 application ( both using Newtonsoft.Json & RestSharp)

Application A serializes a list of objects and returns a string

Application B takes takes the string deserializes back to the list
```

For the last 2 days I tried multiple solutions that I found on the internet.. nothing works for me..

Can someone please advise what I'm missing here ?

Thank you.

Please let me know if I should add more details.

Class used to serialize & deserialize:

```
public class Email
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Api create response:

```
//Response
List<Email> apiResponse = new List<Email>();
Task<List<Email>> get = getEmails.GetEmails();
apiResponse = (await get);
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponse);
```

Api response:

```
[{"Reference":"01010101","ShortDescription":"Customers Unable To Navigate 
Beyond \"Choose A Level\" Screen on appllicaiton"}, 
{"Reference":"02020202","ShortDescription":"Example2: messenger issue"}]
```

Response deserialization:

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient("http://servername:81/");
        client.ClearHandlers();
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/emails/HandleGetRequest", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddQueryParameter("query", queryString);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        List<Email> apiResponse;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            // OK 
            apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Email>>(response.Content);
        }
        else
        {
            // NOK
            apiResponse = null;
            Console.Write("ERROR: {0}", response.Content);
            log.FatalFormat("ERROR: {0}", response.Content);

        }

        return apiResponse;
```

Error received:

```
[ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestProject.Models.Email].]
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, 
Type initialType, Type targetType) +243
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, 
CultureInfo culture, Type targetType) +123 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType) +485


[JsonSerializationException: Error converting value " 
[{"Reference":"01010101","ShortDescription":"Customers Unable To Navigate 
Beyond \"Choose A Level\" Screen on appllicaiton"}, 
{"Reference":"02020202","ShortDescription":"Example2: messenger issue"}]" 
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestProject.Models.Email]'. Path '', 
line 1, position 6633.]
```

Comment: You should share one [MCVE] next time.

Comment: Hi @aloisdg, will keep that in mind for any of the further posts. Thank you.

Comment: What is the signature of the function that returns the deserialized response? What is the line you're getting this error?

Comment: Hi Cid, not sure how to respond to your question due to my lack of knowledge but I'll try. The error is generated here: apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Email>>(response.Content); I used the debugger and this is failing inside the Newtonsoft classes

Comment: You can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6f4Ubr) that the JSON you've pasted deserliases fine. I suspect this is *not* what is in `response.Content`. What you've got there has been quoted, so what you're trying to deserialise is a JSON string containing that entire content. I'm not familiar with RestSharp, but I suspect you're manually serialising to a string and then passing it into the framework which is then running that string through some serialisation again.

Comment: Hi @Charles Mager, I'm having a look into the response string, I think there might be the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment now I think I've proved the theory...

You can see in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6f4Ubr) that the deserialisation of the JSON as described works correctly.

What seems to be happening here is that the `response.Content` is that JSON, but escaped. It's likely the whatever server framework you're using has serialised the result (the `string`) again.

You can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8JlLn5) that this reproduces the same error.

At the very least replacing the line:

```cs
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponse);
```

with simply

```cs
return apiResponse;
```

Should result in the correct serialisation (the framework will do it, if you need to configure it further than look at the relevant docs).

However, I'd also note from [the docs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Serialization) that RestSharp has its own JSON deserialisation built in, so there's probably no need to use `Newtonsoft.Json` on the receiving end either. You can see in the [recommended usages](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) there are various generic overloads like `Execute<T>` that allow you to specify the return type and the framework will deserialise this.

```cs
IRestResponse<List<Email>> response = client.Execute<List<Email>>(request);
List<Email> apiResponse = response.Data;
```

I'd suggest reading the RestSharp documentation and some examples.

Comment: Hi @Charles, this is indeed correct. I noted that if i create: `string test = "[{\"Reference\":\"-\",\"ShortDescription\":\"No matches found.\"}]"` and invoke `DeserializeObject` agains it, it would work ( as the escape chars are removed). The `response.content` contains `"[{\"Reference\":\"-\",\"ShortDescription\":\"No matches found.\"}]"` but the escape characters are not removed, generating the issue. I have used your suggestion and it is working but I had to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Email>>(response.Content)'` as the `response.Data` is null. Thank you for your help ! <3

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is the IList in the deserialize part.

Try:

```
apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Email>>(response.Content);
```

Comment: *"I think"* and *"try"* seem to be unsure answers

Comment: sorry about that Tony, I tried with List / IList / ienumerable. and  didn't correct in the post. I fixed that now

Comment: Yeah, I went for the educated quick answer based off the IList.

Comment: @Cid why not upvote instead of posting almost the same answer? If some terms bother you, feel free to submit an edit of this answer.

Comment: @aloisdg because my answer is totally different. Please read it.

Comment: my issue was the .Content was missing. Cheers